# Click Event Handler in Child Window Not Firing

Tags: wpf, multithreading

In my first foray into a (relatively simple) multithreaded WPF application, I am running into a problem trying to run a timer on one thread and recording click events in a child window of another. The timer code on the separate thread runs fine, but everything I've tried with the button event handler in the other window results in zero click events being recognized.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public static bool isCompleted = false;

public void DoSomething()
{
    TestWindow testWindow = new TestWindow(testID);
    testWindow.Owner = this;
    testWindow.Show();

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(RunTestTimer);
    timerThread.Start();

    do
    {
    } while (!isCompleted);

    // Some code to execute when the timer thread is done
}

...

public void RunTestTimer() { ... some stuff here, runs fine... }
```

TestWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
        Background="White" Name="btnRespond"/>
</Grid>
```

TestWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public static Test Test;

public TestWindow(int testID)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    btnRespond.Click += btnRespond_Click;
    btnRespond.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    Test = new Test()
    {
        TestID = testID
    };

    Test.Responses = new List<Response>();
    Test.StartedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

internal void btnRespond_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Test.Responses.Add(new Response()
        {
            TestID = Test.TestID,
            RespondedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
        });
}
```

`Test.Responses` is always empty. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried setting some break point to see if the actual handler is triggered?

Comment: Yes. It isn't triggered. But I'm registering the handler in the constructor of `TestWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, the UI thread was processing the loop I was using to prevent execution of the later code until the thread's action was completed, and so, because the UI thread was busy in the MainWindow, the click event wasn't available to be triggered in the child window.

I fixed this by using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead and providing it a callback for the [RunWorkCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to execute the code I was trying to delay until completion of the separate thread. That worked like a charm thanks to this post: [Threading with Callback example does not work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302966/threading-with-callback-example-does-not-work)

You live and you learn.